# Android CookieManager not overwriting cookie values

Tags: android, xamarin, cookies, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm working on a hybrid Xamarin.Forms app where some parts are native and some parts are displayed as the mobile web pages from the website.  Because of this we have to sync our native authentication with cookies to make sure both show the same data. I've made a dependency service to manage the cookies, we basically just retrieve them or set them.  To be clear, This code worked at one point, but now doesn't seem to be anymore.  The issue is that when a user logs in and we have cookie values to overwrite existing cookies, they're not being over written like in the past.

I think this could stem from the fact that our website flagged all their cookies as secure and android isn't allowing us to overwrite secure cookies.  Is this a common problem? There's some more info:

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Webkit.CookieManager.SetCookie/p/System.String/System.String/

Here’s what I use to set our cookies on android:

```
    public void SetCookies(List<Cookie> cookies) {
        foreach (Cookie cookie in cookies) {
            CookieManager.Instance.SetCookie(cookie.Domain, cookie.ToString());
        }
    }
```

And here's some sample logging I see when that function SHOULD set cookies after a user's logged in.  I'll note, specifically, that their cartID isn't getting updated with the new value coming in.

```
Cookies Coming in => ShopperId=5; LoginId=3; CartId=4; 
Cookies BEFORE set => http://apps.test.com: https://apps.test.com: CartId=2; http://www.test.com: https://www.test.com: CartId=2; 
Cookies AFTER set => http://apps.test.com:  ShopperId=5;  LoginId=3; https://apps.test.com: CartId=2;  ShopperId=5;  LoginId=3; http://www.test.com:  ShopperId=5;  LoginId=3; https://www.test.com: CartId=2;  ShopperId=5;  LoginId=3;
```

Comment: Make sure that it is the same host, path and name. If it is the same, you can call `removeAllCookie ` and then call `SetCookies`.

Comment: Thanks Joe!  My cookies have always had the same host, name, and path. I've tried using removeAllCookies but the problem is, some of our web pages we display have form validation cookies, and with how often we're syncing the cookies, those seem to get cleared and then forms can't be submitted by users.